# I get an error while adding value fields to pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

G'day,

I have an excel macro where i combine my data at the end into a pivot table. However i also have a sub that adds a value field to the table. It looks like this:

```
Sub AddValuesField()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As String
    Dim pf_Name As String
    
    Dim sDatasheet  As String
    Dim sPivotName  As String
    sPivotName = "Pivot1"
    sDatasheet = "Documents with extracted fields"

    Sheets(sPivotName).Select
    Set pvt = Sheets(sPivotName).PivotTables("PivotTable1")
   
    pf = Sheets(sDatasheet).Range("A1").Value
    pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields(pf), pf, xlSum
End sub
```

The name of the column is stored in pf(pivotfield). I however get the most descriptive error i dream of receiving: "1004 object defined error"

I hope that someone here can help me out :)

gr,
Menno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caption of the new Data Field must be different from the existing fields in the Pivot Table.

Basically, the name of the pivotfield and it's caption cannot both be the `pf` variable

Adding "Sum of " would fix the issue, but so would adding any other string to differentiate the new field.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a field as `Sum` to your Pivot-Table, you need to add the words `"Sum of"` before the `PivotField` name.

Change your line:

```
pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields(pf), pf, xlSum
```

to:

```
pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields(pf), "Sum of " & pf, xlSum
```

**Note**: you don't need to `Select` your worksheet, you can simply use `Set pvt = Sheets(sPivotName).PivotTables("PivotTable1")` without selecting it first.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I however select the sheet because i want to user to see it when the program ends thats why :)

Comment: @Menno got it :)